# Из-за чего может возникнуть исключение out of range?

Tags: c++, qt

Приветствую. Я разрабатываю перетаскиваемые вкладки, как в браузерах. Вот код `mouseMoveEvent`'а для моего кастомного `QTabBar`:

```
void MagicTabBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e){
    if(this->count() > 1){//если вкладок больше одной
        QRect r = this->parentWidget()->geometry();
        r.setHeight(this->rect().height());
        if(r.contains(e->globalPos())){ //проверка находится ли курсор мыши внутри QTabBar
            QTabBar::mouseMoveEvent(e);
        }
        else{// Если перетянули вкладку за границы QTabBar, она стала окном
            MagicTabWidget* mtw = new MagicTabWidget;

            qobject_cast<MagicTabBar*>(mtw->tabBar())->Position = (this->Position+this->window()->pos())-mapToGlobal(tabRect(this->currentIndex()).topLeft());
            this->releaseMouse();
            mtw->resize(this->parentWidget()->size());
            mtw->addTab(qobject_cast<QTabWidget*>(this->parentWidget())->currentWidget(),tabText(this->currentIndex())); // ERROR HERE!
            mtw->show();
            mtw->tabBar()->grabMouse();
        }
    }
    else{ //если вкладка одна, то просто двигаем окно
        this->window()->move(e->globalPos()-Position);
    }
}
```

`MagicTabBar` и `MagicTabWidget` - мои классы, унаследованные от `QTabBar`, `QTabWidget` соответственно. Программа крашится весьма любопытным образом. Если вкладку тянуть медленно, то всё нормально. Но если резко дернуть её за пределы `QTabBar`, вылетает исключение `Debug error! Program:QtCored.dll File: global/qglobal.cpp ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[] "index out of range", file qlist.h, line 545`. При том, что я вообще нигде не использую `QList`. Причина ошибки - строка, возле которой комментарий "ERROR". Что в ней может быть не так? И почему работает, когда тянешь медленно вкладку, а если быстро - нет?

Comment: @Abyx так я уже и так точно знаю, что ошибка здесь: `qobject_cast<QTabWidget*>(this->parentWidget())->currentWidget()`. ParentWidget в данном случае - `QTabWidget`.

Comment: qt какой версии-то?

Comment: @strangeqargo Qt 5.7

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-18883 вот в этот недофикшенный баг смотрел?

Comment: @strangeqargo теперь посмотрел, да, это оно. Теперь понятно хотя бы причина, буду обходные пути  придумывать. Спасибо.

Comment: я тогда ответом оформлю, ибо есть любители делать ответы из чужих комментов :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

причина в недофикшенном [баге](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-18883), надеюсь автор приведет решение после расследования

Comment: Да, как напишу workaround, обязательно приведу решение.

Comment: Скажите, а этот `ASSERT failure` можно перехватить и обработать? Или это слишком фатальная ошибка?

Comment: практически - нельзя.  можно только не доходить до него

Comment: Я хотел переопределить метод `removeTab();` - крашится именно из-за него, но проблема в том, что он использует много приватных полей и методов `QTabBar`. Потом наткнулся на `D-Pointer`ы, думал делать через них, но на этапе компиляции возникает ошибка: `невозможно обратится к private член QTabBar::d_func()`. Решил определить свой метод `d_func()`, такой же как в оригинале, но не нашел исходников.

Comment: "However, this patch makes it work for the one in QDockWidget"   я так понимаю, патч там вмерджен. MagicTabWidget от кого наследуется? может быть они умудрились не для всех виджетов починить?

Comment: MagicTabWidget, наследуется, как я писал, от QTabWidget

Comment: есть обходные пути? а то тоже встретился с этой проблемой